# very simple ruby combobox - text parse prolem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

tried to create simple dropdown in ruby - like that :

```
<%= select_tag(:origin_id, '<option value="1">Lisbon</option>') %>
```

and I received an empy one.
this is the generated html

```
  <select id="origin_id" name="origin_id">&lt;option alue=&quot;1&quot;&gt;Lisbon&lt;/option&gt;/select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark your HTML as safe to avoid Rails to escape it.

```
<%= select_tag(:origin_id, '<option value="1">Lisbon</option>'.html_safe) %>
```